# Sharing gradle dependencies: version catalog vs plugin

Tags: gradle, gradle-dependencies

Gradle is working on new features for [sharing dependency versions between projects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html) that will provide central locations (`settings.gradle`, `libs.versions.toml`) for declaring common dependencies.

It's already possible (and easy) to share a `dependencies` block through a plugin, so what is the downside of the plugin approach to sharing dependencies, versus the new version catalogs and dependency bundles? What do these new features improve upon?

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on how to share a `dependencies` block through a plugin for comparison?

Comment: I was thinking of [precompiled script plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:precompiled_plugins), but any way you package it you can add a `dependencies` block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a thorough answer. However, let me share what I think makes a difference. We need to keep in mind that Gradle is built around developer productivity and making builds as fast as possible.

Centralizing common dependency declaration makes sense to be supported out of the box. Currently, there is a good chance that when you look at different Gradle projects, each one of them may implement a different approach to this. Cédric Champeau iterates over some existing pattern in this [blog](https://melix.github.io/blog/2021/03/version-catalogs.html). Having a standard solution makes it easier to get started as developer. Cédric further states

> Long story short: the presence of a catalog makes discoverability and maintenance easier, but it doesn’t remove any of the flexibility that Gradle offers. We’re thinking about ways to enforce that all direct dependencies are declared via a catalog in the future.

Declaring dependencies in `libs.versions.toml` allows Gradle to skip build script compilation when dependency versions are changed. This is significantly faster than changing the same in a script plugin. As a side-effect of declaring dependencies in `libs.versions.toml`, we may see third-party tooling that update dependencies automatically in the future.

Comment: Rereading this answer, I think it boils down to "standardization and performance". That sounds like the right answer.